# Access denied error using vsts

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, publish

I'm trying to create a wcf service in a lab using vsts.

I have created a build definition that works using a msbuild task. It then uses robocopy to copy the relevant dlls to a remote directory inside a lab using the Publish Artifacts step.

However, I need the content to be created as a windows service, and started after it has been published. It seems like something is running since I see a created log file about 9 minutes after a successful publish, but i cannot see my service inside the services menu, or in IIS.

When I try to run a bat script (using the run script step) that does an sc create, I get an **access denied** error even though on the vsts build definition I have given the step permission to modify the environment.

This is the full error:

```
2018-05-17T13:00:13.7702615Z ##[section]Starting: Run script GloBill/InstallBackEnd.bat
2018-05-17T13:00:13.7705444Z ==============================================================================
2018-05-17T13:00:13.7705561Z Task         : Batch Script
2018-05-17T13:00:13.7705655Z Description  : Run a windows cmd or bat script and optionally allow it to change the environment
2018-05-17T13:00:13.7705748Z Version      : 1.1.3
2018-05-17T13:00:13.7705824Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2018-05-17T13:00:13.7705924Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613733)
2018-05-17T13:00:13.7706023Z ==============================================================================
2018-05-17T13:00:13.7775377Z ##[command]C:\agent\_work\1\s\GloBill\InstallBackEnd.bat 
2018-05-17T13:00:13.8030595Z 
2018-05-17T13:00:13.8031049Z C:\agent\_work\1\s>sc create GloBillBackEnd ../Services/GloBill.WS.exe 
2018-05-17T13:00:13.8048684Z [SC] OpenSCManager FAILED 5:
2018-05-17T13:00:13.8048781Z 
2018-05-17T13:00:13.8048901Z Access is denied.
2018-05-17T13:00:13.8048957Z 
2018-05-17T13:00:13.8064609Z ##[error]Process completed with exit code 5.
2018-05-17T13:00:13.8073202Z ##[section]Finishing: Run script GloBill/InstallBackEnd.bat
```

I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: What's the batch script? Can you show the detail whole build logs here? Besides, please make sure the agent machine can access to youe IIS server.

Comment: What's the build logs (by settings `system.debug` as `true`)?

Comment: The portion of the build log that has the failure above is from the log.

Comment: Hey, system.debug is false.

Comment: So you can set system.debug as true and provider detail build logs here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was trying to deploy a release from a hosted agent that resided on another machine.

I had to configure a new agent solely for deploying, then i had to tweak my installation script a little by adding the -executionpolicy bypass command.

Here is the new script:
(%1 is the file path)

```
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -File %1 -username Username -password ****** -exepath *exe* -serviceName *svcName*
```